# How do I get the Here Flutter SDK (Navigate)

Tags: flutter, here-api

How do I get the Here Flutter SDK (Navigate), could not find anywhere to request it

Answer (score 0):

Get in contact with HERE sales via https://developer.here.com/help#how-can-we-help-you - Flutter Navigate is currently available only on request since it's still Beta.

Comment: Thanks for the help.I'm looking to use offline maps. Also, hot-reload is not working with the current Flutter SDK (Explore). At the moment I'm struggling to use the Flutter SDK efficiently due to the bugs and missing features.

Comment: Hot reload will be fixed with the next release 4.4 of Flutter Explore. If you need full offline, then it's not available in any 4.x products yet, you are right.